# Using Sublime's regex search/replace with \Z

Tags: regex, replace, editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Sublime seems to think that `\Z` matches the actual end of the file,
*and* each `\n` leading up to it.

Is this a bug in Sublime
(meaning, Sublime or something it's using),
or is it the the correct behavior
and I'm just confused about how it *should* work?

Here is a simplified concrete demonstration:

This is the search replace:

```
   Find What:\Z
Replace With:y
```

Here are 4 egs with:

```
    - the original file contents
    - the actual   result
    - my  expected result
```

## eg0 - `\n` at the end: 0

(Works as I expected.)

original:

```
x0
x
x
x
```

actual:

```
x0
x
x
xy
```

expected:

```
x0
x
x
xy
```

((
The Stackexchange formatting messes up here,
and starts ignoring the `#.*` lines,
and I don't know how to fix it,
but the `pre`-tag contents are still fine.
**EDIT:**
The actual formatting in the post itself works,,
but the formatting is messed up in the *preview* of the post (that appears below the editing box).
))

## eg1 - `\n` at the end: 1

original:

```
x1
x
x
x
```

actual:

```
x1
x
x
xy
y
```

expected:

```
x1
x
x
x
y
```

## eg2 - `\n` at the end: 2

original:

```
x2
x
x
x
```

actual:

```
x2
x
x
xy
y
y
```

expected:

```
x2
x
x
x

y
```

## eg3 - `\n` at the end: 3

original:

```
x3
x
x
x
```

actual:

```
x3
x
x
xy
y
y
y
```

expected:

```
x3
x
x
x


y
```

Comment: Well, does `\z` --> `y` replacement work as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that gets the result I expected (ie, identical to the `expected` pre-block for each eg above). But is `\Z` *supposed* to work as it does?

Comment: `\Z` matches before the final newline in the document, too.

Comment: So... by that description... you mean `\Z`-->`y` should insert a *single* `y` in all cases, just *before* the final `\n?`?

Comment: Have a look at my answer, I found the exact reference to the Boost regex syntax. The point is that PCRE and Boost are a bit different, in many flavors (except in Python `re`) `\Z` matches at the end or the final newline in the string. Boost seems to be another exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is worth to note that Sublime Text uses Boost regex engine in the Search and Replace feature.

In order to obtain the behavior you expect, you need to use `\z` anchor that matches **the very end of the string/document**.

The `\Z` can match before optional number of newlines at the end, see [this Boost regex reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html):

> `\z` Matches at the end of a buffer only (the same as `\\'`).
>
> `\Z` Matches a zero-width assertion consisting of an optional sequence of newlines at the end of a buffer: equivalent to the regular expression `(?=\v*\z)`. **Note that this is subtly different from Perl which behaves as if matching `(?=\n?\z)`.**

So, this is no bug, it is expected behavior of `\Z` anchor.

Comment: Thanks! I just discovered regex101.com and tested [`\Z`](https://www.regex101.com/r/fC5gW9/1) vs [`\z`](https://regex101.com/r/kY2hG0/1) there, and yeah, I think I get it now. It was prolly `\z` that I wanted in the first place in the actual concrete practical context I just ran into this,, I'd just never had to look into  the distinction before.